# Incorrect output of database program

Tags: java

I am doing practice for JDBC and using NetBeans 8.1. I created a table in MS Access and wrote a program. But the problem is that when I pass column index then my program runs successfully. But I pass column name as in my table in MS Access then there occurs an error that

> Column not found

I am pasting code of my program and try to explain my problem further.

```
package database;
import java.sql.*;

public class Database {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       String url = "jdbc:odbc:personDSN";    
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
       String sql = "SELECT *FROM students";
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

       while(rs.next())
       {
         String Name = rs.getString(2);
         String add = rs.getString(3);
         String pNum = rs.getString(4);
         System.out.println(Name + " "  + add + " "  + pNum);
       }
       con.close();
     } 
     catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException sqlEx)
     {
        System.out.println(sqlEx);
     }
  }
}
```

As you can see in while loop that i have passed column index in getString() function. In this case my program runs successfully. But when i pass name of field/attribute which is in my database table, then it gives me error that "Column not found". For example if I pass getString("name") then it gives me above error.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Note: I have checked again and again that there is no spelling mistake in my parameter opposite to actual table in ms access.

Comment: can you show your database? Remeber that in MS Access you see the column names only in design mode - the display names might be different. It might be good to see your code using the column names as well.

Comment: attach db content. and change sql query "SELECT *" on SELECT Name,Address,etc ..

Comment: I changed the query and problem solved. Thanks kain64b.